# Simple Haskell calculator, using Maybe for error handling

Tags: beginner, haskell, functional-programming, calculator

I'm reading through [Write Yourself a Scheme](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/) after finishing going through Learn You a Haskell. I attempted one of the early exercises: writing a program to get an operator and two numbers and do a computation. It works fine.

Things I would like to know:

How should I structure a program, in terms of building larger functions out of smaller functions? Are there redundancies in my code?

What's the most effective way to use the Maybe type to indicate failure when main is of type `IO ()`? Is my `checkSuccess` an appropriate way to do this?

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

-- parses the first arithmetic operator in a string
parseOperator :: String -> Maybe Char
parseOperator [] = Nothing
parseOperator (x:xs)
    | x == '*' = Just '*'
    | x == '/' = Just '/'
    | x == '+' = Just '+'
    | x == '-' = Just '-'
    | otherwise = parseOperator xs

parseNum :: String -> Maybe Double
parseNum x =
    let parsed = reads x :: [(Double,String)]
    in case parsed of
        [(a,"")] -> Just a
        [(_,_)] -> Nothing
        [] -> Nothing

compute :: Maybe Char -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double
compute Nothing _ _ = Nothing
compute _ Nothing _ = Nothing
compute _ _ Nothing = Nothing
compute (Just c) (Just x) (Just y)
    | c == '*' = Just $ x * y
    | c == '/' = Just $ x / y
    | c == '+' = Just $ x + y
    | c == '-' = Just $ x - y

checkSuccess :: Maybe Double -> IO ()
checkSuccess Nothing = putStrLn "Failed. Check correctness of inputs"
checkSuccess (Just r) = putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ (show r)

runSequence :: String -> String -> String -> IO ()
runSequence os xs ys =
    checkSuccess $ compute (parseOperator os) (parseNum xs) (parseNum ys)

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter operator: * / + -"
    operator <- getLine

    putStrLn "Enter first number"
    first <- getLine

    putStrLn "Enter second number"
    second <- getLine

    runSequence operator first second
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd further suggest to split `compute` into two parts:

1. Getting the right operation from a given character:

   ```
   op :: Char -> Maybe (Double -> Double -> Double)
   op '*' = Just (*)
   op '/' = Just (/)
   op '+' = Just (+)
   op '-' = Just (-)
   op _   = Nothing
   ```

   This accepts a character, and either produces a function corresponding to the character, or `Nothing`.
2. Applying the operation on values, taking into account all possible `Maybe`s:

   ```
   compute' :: Maybe Char -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double
   compute' c x y = (c >>= op) <*> x <*> y
   ```

   Here `c >>= op` results into `Maybe (Double -> Double -> Double)`, where the result is `Nothing` if the character is `Nothing` or if it doesn't match any supported operation. And then we use twice `<*>` from `Control.Applicative`, which, specialized for `Maybe`, applies `Maybe (a -> b)` to `Maybe a` yelding `Maybe b`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try it out, but you can write something like

```
parseOperator (x:xs)
    | x `elem` "*/+-" = Just x
    | otherwise = parseOperator xs
```

And you could write

```
compute :: Maybe Char -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double -> Maybe Double
compute (Just '*') (Just x) (Just y) = Just $ x * y
compute (Just '/') (Just x) (Just y) = Just $ x / y
compute (Just '+') (Just x) (Just y) = Just $ x + y
compute (Just '-') (Just x) (Just y) = Just $ x - y
compute _ _ _ = Nothing
```